# Add contextual link to panels "custom content" pane?

Tags: 7, panels

I am wondering if there is a way to add a contextual link to a "custom content" pane? For example my "block" panes have the block contextual link that allow for easy edit. But is there a way to do this for regular panes?

I am trying to find a way to make Panel's more accessible to the "non technical user". Having to click Panel Content, then find the gear, then edit that. Is a little too much work that can easily get lost.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try FAPE, Field API Pane Editor. It is a separate module from ctools.

It does make it much easier for non-technical users to edit a field or a single pane of a page.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work. FAPE allow to edit entity fields directly using contextual links, the problem is that Panels Custom Content feature is not an entity field, so the contextual links don't appears.